# JS async (async/await) returns promise but also executes the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

the JavaScript async function returns promise but also executes the function. It kind of defeats the purpose. Please explain. Also is there a way to return promise and not execute by using async/await only (not Promise).

https://jsfiddle.net/ravilution/woxkossp/

```
function wait(ms){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while(end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

const fn = async (value) => {
  console.log("start fn ", value)
  wait(2000);
  console.log("end fn ", value)
  return value;
}

const main = async () => {
  var promiseForFn = fn(3);
  console.log("promiseForFn ", promiseForFn);
  var value = await promiseForFn;
  console.log("value ", value);
}

main()
```

**OR**

https://jsfiddle.net/ravilution/o44kbj9p/

```
const wait = async(ms) => {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}

const fn = async(value) => {
  console.log("start fn ", value)
  await wait(2000);
  console.log("end fn ", value)
  return value;
}

const main = async() => {
  var promiseForFn = fn(3);
  console.log("promiseForFn ", promiseForFn);
  var value = await promiseForFn;
  console.log("value ", value);
}

main()
```

> Marking a function as `async` is not what makes it truly asynchronous **is the answer**. Thanks to @another-guy

Comment: Your `wait` function is synchronous. When you use it from `fn` what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @another-guy please help me understand. I converted wait to async. Still does not seem to be working as expected.
https://jsfiddle.net/ravilution/o44kbj9p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There are many ways to achieve asynchronosity of code. Callbacks, built-in functions like `setTimeout`, and `Promises` are a few of commonly known ones.
- Marking a function as `async` is *not* what makes it *truly* asynchronous. It allows you to use a keyword `await` in places where you want to wait on Promises.
- Yeah, `await/async` only work with `Promise`. They are useful for expressing branching and more complex flow control in imperative (sync) style applied to asynchronous code.

Try the following code and see how it works, hope it helps:

---

```
function wait(ms, text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('complete', text);
      resolve({});
    }, ms);
  });
};

async function doTwoThings() {    // This func will return a Promise
  await wait(2000, 'BBB');        // - to which you can subscribe with `.then`
  await wait(1000, 'AAA');        // - or `await` on within another `async` function.
  return 'Both done';
}

doTwoThings()
  .then(
     result => console.info('Done done done!', result),
     err => console.error('Oooops', err)
  );
```

Comment: I come from C# world. And thought mentioning async will make the function async. My bad. Deep down the chain doesn't the final function behave synchronous all the time? Shouldn't that function tell everyone in the top, please don't wait on me, have this promise until I get back. And that promise I thought will get created just by mentioned async, like in C#.

I will accept the answer.

Comment: `Deep down the chain doesn't the final function behave synchronous all the time?` yes, it has to. And this is why I do `doTwoThings().then( ... )` -- I don't think it's possible to `await` on the root level. At least, I'm not aware of the way to do that...

Comment: @ravi - just adding the async keyword to a function in c# does Not make anything async. It just allows you to use await in that method

Comment: @FredrikLundin. Right. Returning Task<Object> does. Which is Promise in JS. I can understand everything now.

Comment: @Ravi while maybe technically they're not necessarily a 100% precise match so to speak, I ended up using pretty much the same mental model because this model is a) simple; b) "good enough"; c) easy to learn (because is built on what I already know). Yes, I came to JS/TS from the .NET realms too.

Answer (score 0):

async keyword should be used ONLY with functions that uses await in their code block. In your case, "wait" function is synchronous (and blocks the event loop) - so the async word is not required.